# UIRefreshControl adding duplicate cells in collectionview

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently having issues refreshing my `collectionview` feed using **UIRefreshControl**. The refresh works fine, however it *duplicates the number of `cells`* and continues to append more items to the **movieDays** `array` and **sort** of randomly rearranges the order of the *items*. I've also tried setting the `array` to `nil` each time it refreshes, but then I get a **fatal error saying the `indexPath` is out of range**. Does anyway know the correct way to set this up?

Thanks a lot

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleRefresh), for: .valueChanged)

    collectionView.refreshControl = refreshControl
    self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true

    fetchData()
}

var movieDays: [MoviesByScheduleByDay]? = []

fileprivate func fetchData() {

    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

    dispatchGroup.enter()
    Service.shared.fetchMoviesBySchedule { (movieDays, err) in
        if let err = err    {
            print("Failed to fetch movies", err)
            return
        }
        self.movieDays = movieDays?.data
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }

    dispatchGroup.enter()
    Service.shared.fetchFeaturedMovies { (movies, err) in
        if let err = err    {
            print("Failed to fetch featured movies", err)
            return
        }
        self.headerMovies = movies?.data ?? []
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }

    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
        print("complete dispatch")
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
        self.collectionView.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
    }
}

@objc func handleRefresh()    {
    fetchData()
}
```

Comment: sure your single response has no duplicates ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
fileprivate func fetchData() {

   if self.movieDays != nil
   {
      self.movieDays.removeAll() 
      self.headerMovies.removeAll()
   }

   let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

    dispatchGroup.enter()
    Service.shared.fetchMoviesBySchedule { (movieDays, err) in
        if let err = err    {
            print("Failed to fetch movies", err)
            return
        }
        self.movieDays = movieDays?.data
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }

    dispatchGroup.enter()
    Service.shared.fetchFeaturedMovies { (movies, err) in
        if let err = err    {
            print("Failed to fetch featured movies", err)
            return
        }
        self.headerMovies = movies?.data ?? []
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }

    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
        print("complete dispatch")
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
        self.collectionView.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
    }
}
```

Comment: the op overwrites `self.movieDays = movieDays?.data`  so there is no need to clear

Comment: Yeah Sh_Khan seems to be correct. using removeAll() doesn't seem to fix it